# ESPN Fantasy API request filtering with X-Fantasy-Filter header

Tags: json, api, request-headers, espn

I'm using `requests` to pull in NBA player stats from the ESPN Fantasy API. Downstream I'm building a pandas df. One thing I'm having trouble with is filtering the request for fields that are deeper in the JSON nesting. I'm able to filter `status` and sort by `PercOwned` in my header, but I can't seem to filter for items like `statSplitTypeId` or `auctionValue`. Any thoughts?

url: https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/fba/seasons/2022/segments/0/leagues/1747675438?view=kona_player_info

current headers:

```
headers = {
  'X-Fantasy-Filter': '{"players":\
      {"filterStatus":{"value":["FREEAGENT","WAIVERS","ONTEAM"]},\
          "sortPercOwned":{"sortAsc":false,"sortPriority":1}}}'
}
```

Example JSON response

````
{
    "players": [
        {
            "draftAuctionValue": 0,
            "id": 3032977,
            "keeperValue": 1,
            "keeperValueFuture": 1,
            "lineupLocked": false,
            "onTeamId": 4,
            "player": {
                "active": true,
                "defaultPositionId": 4,
                "draftRanksByRankType": {
                    "STANDARD": {
                        "auctionValue": 64,
                        "published": false,
                        "rank": 2,
                        "rankSourceId": 0,
                        "rankType": "STANDARD",
                        "slotId": 0
                    }
                },
                "droppable": false,
                "eligibleSlots": [
                    3,
                    6,
                    8,
                    9,
                    10,
                    11,
                    12,
                    13
                ],
                "firstName": "Giannis",
                "fullName": "Giannis Antetokounmpo",
                "ownership": {
                    "activityLevel": null,
                    "auctionValueAverage": 64.22289156626506,
                    "auctionValueAverageChange": -2.9199655765920767,
                    "averageDraftPosition": 2.6674573758339513,
                    "averageDraftPositionPercentChange": -0.6431361088656256,
                    "date": 1637244022069,
                    "leagueType": 0,
                    "percentChange": -0.006086844650013745,
                    "percentOwned": 99.95081910133877,
                    "percentStarted": 85.24790654758796
                },
            },
            "rosterLocked": true,
            "status": "ONTEAM",
            "tradeLocked": false```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can filter on statSplits with `"filterStatsForSplitTypeIds":{"value":[1]}` and just add in the id into the value list. I couldn't work out though what id corresponds to what split.

As far as the auctionValue, I couldn't find that being implimented in any of the requests to the api.

```
import requests


headers = {
  'X-Fantasy-Filter': '{"players":\
      {"filterStatus":{"value":["FREEAGENT","WAIVERS","ONTEAM"]},\
       "filterStatsForSplitTypeIds":{"value":[0,1,2]},\
          "sortPercOwned":{"sortAsc":false,"sortPriority":1}}}'
}

url = 'https://fantasy.espn.com/apis/v3/games/fba/seasons/2022/segments/0/leagues/1747675438?view=kona_player_info'
jsonData = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
```